How to change the sender address using mailutils and postfix?
May 27 14:19:33 localhost postfix/qmgr[21793]: 87FD870AD12: from=user@localhost,
size=398, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
May 27 14:20:03 localhost postfix/smtp[22591]: connect to
mail.rungel.net[95.168.160.148]:25: Connection timed out
May 27 14:20:03 localhost postfix/smtp[22591]: 87FD870AD12:
to=darofoce.utihurol@rungel.net, relay=none, delay=2347, delays=2317/0.12/30/0, dsn=4.4>
I tried changing the name /etc/mailname and /etc/email-addresses but no affect. Ive been looking for the past hour on this issue but there isn't much resources available specifically for this.
Here is my maillog, The first line "from=user@localhost" how can I change that to be user@mydomain.com?
